# html meta tag, avoid browser url change

Tags: html, spring, model-view-controller, jsp

i have the following url in my jsp page of my spring mvc app, my controller froward to the a jsp which has the following:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/app/static/test'"
```

this causes the the page to load correctly, however the browser url changes.

Is it possible to avoid url change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the refresh meta tag triggers a GET /app/static/test (as if you would type it in your browser's address field). there is no way to avoid it.